# problems in dynamic craetion of subdomains in php

Tags: php

Hello
I am creating subdomains in php by the following code.

```
function subd($host,$port,$ownername,$passw,$request) {


  $sock = fsockopen('localhost',2082);

  if(!$sock) {

    print('Socket error');

    exit();

  }

  $authstr = "$ownername:$passw";

  $pass = base64_encode($authstr);

  $in = "GET $request\r\n";

  $in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";

  $in .= "Host:$host\r\n";

  $in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";

  $in .= "\r\n";


  fputs($sock, $in);

  while (!feof($sock)) {

    $result .= fgets ($sock,128);

  }

  fclose( $sock );


  return $result;

}

$domain="memories.mydomain.com";

        $subd="abcdef";

        $request ="frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?domain=$subd&rootdomain=$domain&dir=public_html/$subd&go=Create";

        $host="ftp.mydomain.com";

        $port="2083";

        $ownername="ownername";

        $passw="my_PASSWORD";

        $result=subd($host,$port,$ownername,$passw,$request);

        $show = strip_tags($result);


    $d="http://$subdomainname.$domain";


          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$d.'">';
```

I am seeing in my cpanel sub-domain is creating but i want to redirect to my sob-domains when creation completed but instead of subdomain i am redirecting to  error page which is
http://abcdef.memories.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. What is the problem behind it.Why am i redirecting to unsupported link.?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you're writing an automated front end for an automated front end.  Why don't you just create the subdomain directly in the php script, and skip messing around with cpanel?

Comment: more explanation needed i have to make subdomain for all register users. that's why i am creating it by php script

Comment: I didn't say dont use PHP. You're automating and already automated system. Cpanel is an unnecessary middle man that may not be well suited to solve your problem in this way.  Skip the cpanel, and do what cpanel does behind the scenes, which is run bash scripts and edit certain files to get the subdomains setup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this should be done as a GET request? Doing things on a server via GET that have consequences is NEVER a good idea: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

1. Don't use your own http client. Use curl (good) or something like file_get_contents (not as good)
2. Check if CPanel wants this done as a POST instead.
3. You pass in a port #2083, but then ignore it completely and use a hardcoded port #2082 in the function.
4. Your request URL has no leading `/`, which makes it an invalid request. You can use such paths in an HTML page, because the browser rewrites the `href=""` stuff by putting on the address of the page the link is in - but you're not using a browser. You're rolling your own version.