# subdomain creation problem dynamically in php

Tags: php, cpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problems in dynamic craetion of subdomains in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046575/problems-in-dynamic-craetion-of-subdomains-in-php)

Hi,
I have below code which was working fine on testing server but when i transfer it to iPage server my subdomain is not being create. I m not finding where is coming from .Plz take a look.

```
function subd($host,$port,$ownername,$passw,$request) {

  //$sock = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
  $sock = fsockopen("www.mydomain.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  echo $sock;

  if(!$sock) {
    print('Socket error');
    exit();
  }

  $authstr = "$ownername:$passw";
  $pass = base64_encode($authstr); 

  $in = "GET $request\r\n";
  $in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
  $in .= "Host:$host\r\n";
  $in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";
  $in .= "\r\n";

  fputs($sock, $in);

  while (!feof($sock)) {
    $result .= fgets ($sock,128);
  }

  fclose( $sock );
  return $result;
}
$domain='mydomain.com';

$subd="f1f1f1f1";

$request = "/frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$domain&domain=$subd";
```

Password and userid is with my code. I m not getting any error.When i m echoing this is printing "Resource id #1 " nearby socket printing ($sock).

Comment: Can you tell us how this is any different than [your previous question about this script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046575/problems-in-dynamic-craetion-of-subdomains-in-php)?  It seems like an exact duplicate to me.  Also, you seem to have failed to post all of the appropriate code.  There are *no* echos/prints in the posted code.

Comment: Previously i was getting an error with "socket error" but presently my subdomain is not creating.I m not assuming why this error is occuring.

Answer (score 2):

1) why are you trying to roll your own HTTP client when curl already does it much better

2) what do you think the HTTP request actually sends? (hint you don't initialize the $request variable until after you've closed the socket).

3) is the URL you are publishing to designed to use a published API for adding vhosts?

4) do you think its a good idea to use basic http authentication over a non-secure connection?

5) there is no error checking nor comments in your code

6) "When i m echoing this is printing "Resource id #1 " nearby socket printing" - there is just so many things wrong with this statement, I don't know where to start

You need to find a better place to cut and paste your code from - or learn how to write it yourself.

Comment: Regarding your #2 hint, $request is a parameter to the function. OP doesn't show the function call, but I presume it's there somewhere.